How can I get all my plots on the same image?
I wanted to plot how the results change after different initial conditions, but I don't get much information when all of them are on different images, so I wanted to somehow put all of them on the same image. The problem is that I can't figure out how to do this because I don't understand how to make it work since the values change after each set of initial conditions. The code that I entered is the following:
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t_start, t_end, num_points = 0, 10, 100
dt = (t_end - t_start) / (num_points - 1)

x_system_values = np.zeros(num_points)
y_system_values = np.zeros(num_points)

a = float(input("Enter the coefficient ’a’: "))
b = float(input("Enter the coefficient ’b’: "))
c = float(input("Enter the coefficient ’c’: "))
d = float(input("Enter the coefficient ’d’: "))

    
for m in range(0,2):
    for n in range(0,2):
        x_system, y_system = m, n 
        for i in range(num_points):
            dxdt_system = a * x_system + b * y_system
            dydt_system = c * x_system + d * y_system
            x_system += dxdt_system * dt
            y_system += dydt_system * dt
            x_system_values[i] = x_system
            y_system_values[i] = y_system
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x_system_values, y_system_values)
        plt.xlabel("X")
        plt.ylabel("Y")
        plt.title("Stability")
        plt.legend()

plt.show()

I tried to change the order of the commands, like I put plt.figure() above the for so in this way maybe it will include all. I thought to put the array value in a vector to store them and then make a plot for every column or line in the matrix but I think I may be over complicating this.

Putting plt.figure() before the for loop will ensure that all the plots are on the same figure. Why do you say it doesn't?

Try using subplots. This will allow you to organize everything onto the same figure.
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t_start, t_end, num_points = 0, 10, 100
dt = (t_end - t_start) / (num_points - 1)

x_system_values = np.zeros(num_points)
y_system_values = np.zeros(num_points)

a = float(input("Enter the coefficient ’a’: "))
b = float(input("Enter the coefficient ’b’: "))
c = float(input("Enter the coefficient ’c’: "))
d = float(input("Enter the coefficient ’d’: "))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

for m in range(0,2):
    for n in range(0,2):
        x_system, y_system = m, n 
        for i in range(num_points):
            dxdt_system = a * x_system + b * y_system
            dydt_system = c * x_system + d * y_system
            x_system += dxdt_system * dt
            y_system += dydt_system * dt
            x_system_values[i] = x_system
            y_system_values[i] = y_system
        
        ax.plot(x_system_values, y_system_values)
        ax.set_xlabel("X")
        ax.set_ylabel("Y")
        ax.set_title("Stability")

plt.show()

